# lemonstand in subdirectory nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm running Lemonstand under the subdirectory www.mysite.com/shop/

Here is my location rule for lemonstand:

```
# Lemonstand
location /shop {
    root /home/sites/mysite.com/public_html/shop/;
    index index.php;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME index.php;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING url=$uri&$args;

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 32k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 64k;
}
```

I can access the page at mysite.com/shop.

All the URLS for the shop **should** be like this:

```
mysite.com/shop/category/freight
mysite.com/shop/products/dog-toy
```

When in fact on the page they are structured like this:

```
mysite.com/category/freight
mysite.com/products/dog-toy
```

And the strange thing is, even if I paste in the correct URL to the browser, it **only ever shows** my base /shop/ page, as if the other pages don't exist. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main problems were expression syntax and config structure.

OK. So here's the working config file. best practice was to split up the two locations, and utilize one php block for them both.

First the main controller block, which uses silverstripe CMS, here i'm passing the data straight to the main controller in sapphire.

```
# Main silverstripe declaration
location / {
    index /sapphire/main.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /sapphire/main.php?url=$uri&$args;
}
```

Second was my shop under a sub-directory which ran lemonstand. It was mainly a case of getting the expressions correct, then passing the requests to the relevant path. I didn't set another root or alias here, as the rule was inherited from the re-write.

```
# Shop lemonstand files
location /shop/ {
    index index.php;
    rewrite ^/shop(.*)$ /shop/index.php?q=$1 last;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /shop/index.php?q=$1;
}
```

And finally I used a generic PHP block so I didn't have to duplicate my code in the first two. So any thing that goes through the first two block will pass into here.

```
# PHP controller
location ~ ^(.*?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 32k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 64k;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve php from a different location block.

[**EDIT**] to avoid conflicting with other php scripts, you may use named location.

```
location ^~/shop/ {
    root /home/sites/mysite/public_html;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @anotherPhpSite
}

location @anotherPhpSite {
    include fastcgi_params;

    # Defend against arbitrary PHP code execution
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    # More info:
    # https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/shop/index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /shop/index.php;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING url=$uri&$args;

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 32k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 64k;

}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't quite work. I have the shop running on /shop with a base index file there. But also a base index file in my root which is part of another application. This sends me back the the other application